# How can I represent stdin and stderr with pathlib.Path?

Tags: python, pathlib

I love the `pathlib.Path` api and use it a lot for quick cli tools. Especially with [typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/). I have a few tightly related questions:

- In UNIX cli commands `-` is the de facto standard for stdin. Is that the same under Windows?
- Is there a clean, cross-platform way to have a `pathlib.Path` object (or actually the {POSIX,Windows}Path it automatically becomes) to represent stdin?
- And what about stdout?

Comment: What would you expect such an object to *do*?  It can’t expose directory parts, for instance.  Modern Unix systems do have `/dev/stdin`, but that doesn’t sound like what you want.

Comment: @DavisHerring Have a Path instance p, such that p.open() returns an open file descriptor for stdin, ready for reading.

Comment: This post deals with idea I think you're going after: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98393/context-managers-that-also-deal-with-sys-stdin-and-sys-stdout

I'm sure you were looking for something much simpler though.

Comment: @Sebastian that code predates pathlib and, funny, was the pattern [I was using](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89807) when I asked this. I like functions to be simple, so having one accept just a pathlib.Path for all cases, such that it can call .open() on the parameter without inspection, is what I'm after.

Comment: Have a look at [`clap_stdin`](https://docs.rs/clap-stdin/latest/clap_stdin/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-platform pseudo file name for standard input and standard output.

In POSIX, it's `/dev/stdin` for standard input and `/dev/stdout` for standard output, although many CLI tools would accept `-` in the command line arguments as a shorthand for standard input or standard output.

In Windows, it's `CONIN$` for standard input and `CONOUT$` for standard output, or simply `CON` for both standard input and standard output.